# Why do the grid lines not coincide with the coordinates of the axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Grid lines do not coincide with the coordinates of the axes, nor do the coordinates of the points. How can i fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[dutch,10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
        {decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=15cm, axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-1,xmax=19,
            ymin=-1,ymax=16,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18},ytick= 
            {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},
            xticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18},yticklabels= 
            {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},
            ticklabel style={},
            axis line style={very thick, latex-latex},
            axis line style={very thick, ->},
            x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=west,},
            y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=south},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1]
            \draw[step=1cm,black,very thin] (axis cs:0,0) grid (axis cs:5,5);
            \draw[decorate sep={2mm}{5mm},fill] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs: 0,4);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because you set the step size to `step = 1cm`. It works with `step = 10`, though I haven't checked whether that's on accident or on purpose. (PGFPlots uses its own coordinate system which might not be synced to TikZ' *xyz* coordinate system.)

Comment: Either edit your question or ask a new question. Take a good look where `\makeatletter` (before `\tikzset`) and `\makeatother` (after) are in my answer. Your edit had `\makeatletter` after the `\tikzset`, which doesn't make my code work and may break other stuff.

Comment: You should add `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` (at least a relatively recent version of PGFplots) to make sure that the coordinate system inside the `axis` environment is also valid for `\draw` (and similar) macros. This will help (but it will not completely solve the problem, I admit).

Answer (score 5):

You're using

```
step = 1cm
```

which uses a step size of 1 cm.

You want to use

```
step = {(axis direction cs:1,1)}
```

so that TikZ uses the proper step size in relation to the axis coordinate system.

I provide `pgfplots step = <x> by <y>` which uses `step = {(axis direction cs:<x>,<y>)}` for easier input.

---

For placing the shapes along the path, a similar thing is happening. `5mm` is simply not the correct distances between each tick. In addition, the decoration also differentiates between shapes that are placed the given distance between their centers and between their borders.

Here, I'll provide a `pgfplots y shape sep` that takes the step in *y* direction and determines the needed `shape sep` from that but also applies `between centers`.

But you could also just use a loop for it (or maybe a chain with more work beforehand):

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{
  \node[shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=2mm, draw, fill] at (0,#1) {};
}
```

The same is true for the grid (which internally is nothing but two loops) but using the `grid` key with the direction coordinte should help … unless the origin of the PGFPlots coordinate system is not where the origin of the PGF/TikZ picture is. (I don't know whether this can actually be the case.)

---

I'm using

```
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}
```

so we can use `(0, 1)` directly and don't have to use `axis cs:`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass[dutch,10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pgfplots step/.style args={#1 by #2}{step={(axis direction cs:#1,#2)}},
  /pgf/decoration/pgfplots y shape sep/.code=%
    \pgf@process{\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{0}{#1}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/pgf/decoration/shape sep/.expanded={\the\pgf@y,between centers}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  decorate sep/.style 2 args={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      name=shape backgrounds,
      shape=circle,
      shape size={#1},
      pgfplots y shape sep={#2}}}]
\begin{axis}[
  width=15cm, axis lines=middle,
  xmin=-1, xmax=19,
  ymin=-1, ymax=16,
  xtick={0,...,18},       ytick      ={0,...,15},
  xticklabels={0,...,18}, yticklabels={0,...,15},
  axis line style={very thick, ->},
  x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=west,},
  y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=south},
  xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
  unit vector ratio*=1 1 1
]
\draw[very thin, pgfplots step=1 by 1] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\draw[decorate sep={2mm}{1}, fill] (0,1) -- (0,4);
%\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{
%  \node[shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=2mm, draw, fill] at (0,#1) {};
%}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You need to actually figure out what the suggested edit is and not blindly approve it.

Comment: Sorry i'm not a tex expert  i didn't notice \makeatother