# Align tikz grid on pgfplots axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want my grid lines to line up with the ticks in a pgfplots axis. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,axis lines=center]
\draw[gray,step=1cm] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to force PGFPlots' axes you need to adjust the `step` size in relation to its [own coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682631) (it doesn't use step = 1cm by its own but adjusts it so that the intervals fit).

Comment: Thank you, I will make use of this in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the axis unit to be 1cm as well. So that can be done by setting `x=1cm, y=1cm` in the `axis` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=1cm, y=1cm, xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,axis lines=center]
\draw[gray,step=1cm] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't know how to do this. I will accept your answer in ten minutes when I'm allowed to

Comment: One can also use `[scale only axis, width=8cm, height=8cm]`.