# Grid lines are not displayed expectedly when xmin is non-zero

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to `\draw (0,0) grid[xstep=1,ystep=1] (5,5)` in an axis environment, but the output will not be as expected unless xmin (and ymin) is zero.
How do I draw a grid with xstep of 1 for the three examples?

Note: I want to use the grid command in \draw, not the grid option of \axis or drawing with \foreach.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=-1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=-1$},
    ]
    \draw (0,0) grid[xstep=1,ystep=1] (5,5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=0, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=0$},
    ]
    \draw (0,0) grid[xstep=1,ystep=1] (5,5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=1$},
    ]
    \draw (0,0) grid[xstep=1,ystep=1] (5,5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% This works as expected.
\newcommand{\DrawGrid}{
  \draw\foreach\k in {0,1,...,5} {(\k,0) -- (\k,5) (0,\k) -- (5,\k)};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=-1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=-1$},
    ]
    \DrawGrid
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=0, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=0$},
    ]
    \DrawGrid
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=1$},
    ]
    \DrawGrid
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output: the first line is the actual output and the second line is the expected output.
[image: example output]

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately your code is incomplete, as it can‘t compile. Please add the missing parts. By doing so probably your remark „in an axis environment“ will become more clear. Thank you.

Comment: [Q682614](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682614) might be related.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you for your comment. I have added the missing lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `pgfplots step` key from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682631) seem to work as expected.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\tikzset{pgfplots step/.style args={#1 by #2}{step={(axis direction cs:#1,#2)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=-1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=-1$}]
    \draw (0,0) grid[pgfplots step=1 by 1] (5,5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=0, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=0$}]
    \draw (0,0) grid[pgfplots step=1 by 1] (5,5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=1$}]
    \draw (0,0) grid[pgfplots step=1 by 1] (5,5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% This works as expected.
\newcommand{\DrawGrid}{
  \draw\foreach\k in {0,1,...,5} {(\k,0) -- (\k,5) (0,\k) -- (5,\k)};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=-1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=-1$}]
    \DrawGrid
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=0, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=0$}]
    \DrawGrid
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12em, height=12em, xmin=1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=7,
      xlabel={$x_\mathrm{min}=1$}]
    \DrawGrid
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem by writing directly `step={(axis direction cs:1,1)}` without aliasing. Page 243 on https://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots_layers.pdf was helpful.